# Use the same variable for a method and a propertie in an object

Tags: javascript, object

after 1 hour of trying to figure out how I can get this to work I gave up and decided to ask here.

So I created an object :

```
var potion1 = {
        color: "red",
        effect: "strength",
        duration: 1+" minute",
        price: 10,
        test: function() {
            return "test good"
        }
    }
```

And what I'm doing is ask for an input and show the corresponding text.

```
var x = prompt();
x = document.getElementById("potions").innerHTML="Potion 1 : " + potion1[x];
```

The problem is everything works fine with color, effect, duration, price but test return `function() { return "test good" }`

If I use `x = document.getElementById("potions").innerHTML="Potion 1 : " + potion1[x]();` test works fine but all of the others return nothing

So I was wondering if it was possible for x to work with color, effect, duration, price and test.

Comment: the easy answer would be to turn everything into a function

Comment: Did you try to make a conditional assignment to the innerHTML, for example with `innerHTML="Potion 1 : " + typeof potion1[x] == 'function' ? potion1[x]() : potion1[x]`? This is so called conditional (ternary) operator. You can check more about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `test` a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
var potion1 = {
    color: "red",
    effect: "strength",
    duration: 1 + " minute",
    price: 10,
    get test() {
        return "test good"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the easy answer would be to turn everything into a function

or you could use the ternary operator:

```
x = document.getElementById("potions").innerHTML="Potion 1 : " + 
       (typeof potion1[x] != 'function' ? potion1[x] : potion1[x]());
```